# How to get page title?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have web user control, and i need page title. i use the following code:

```
 string s = Page.Title;
```

but it returns an empty string, while the page has title.

Any idea?

Comment: Where did you set the page's title? Also, are you using MasterPages?

Comment: Does the title tag have runat="server" ?

Comment: @RyanMcDonough: [`Page.Title`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.title.aspx) is a property of `Page`(new in 2.0). `runat="server"` is not necessary.

Comment: i'm working on a webcontrol, and i don't mind title tag. i just use this code, in codebehind and i expect it returns the page title. whether it inherits from master page or not.  i just need a safe code to get page title. like when you use favorite button and it offers you page title.

Answer (score 4):

Use this may it help you

```
 string s=this.Parent.Page.Title
```

Comment: if your master is different than parent use this this.Master.Page.Title

Comment: it returns empty string too. as i said i just need a safe code to get page title. like when you use favorite button and it offers you page title

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have

```
<%@ Page Title="" ...
```

at the top of your .aspx. Visual Studio by default sets the page title to an empty string.

Comment: Visual studio by default sets     <title>Untitled Page</title>

Answer (score 0):

The Page title of an asp.net page is set during `FrameworkInitialize`.

This happens before `PreInit`. Your page title should be available in the asp.net page lifecycle after `PreInit`.

Place your code to retrive the title on `Load` of your control and you should be good to go.

Answer (score -1):

User control doesn't have property `Title`.

Your code is using `Page`. That is one Class of .net.

If you want to use `Page.Title`, then Please go on your .aspx page code behind and Try with `this.title`.

```
this.Title will work in .aspx code behind only.
```